# Why does then return a new promise instead of returning promise returned by onFulfilled

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I was wondering why, if then()'s onFulfilled handler returns a promise p2, how come then() returns a new promise p3 instead of just returning p2?

Example:

```
let p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(42);
});

let p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(43);
});

let p3 = p1.then(function(value) {
    // first fulfillment handler
    console.log(value);     // 42
    return p2;
});

p3.then(function(value) {
    // second fulfillment handler
    console.log(value);     // 43
});
```

Why doesn't p1.then() just return p2 instead of making a new promise p3? It would have the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `then()` returns a value *immediately*, before your callback even runs.

It cannot possibly know what you're going to return.

Answer (score -1):

Simply because `p3` is created and returned before the `onFulfilled` callback will run - `then` callbacks are always asynchronous. It cannot know yet what value will be returned in the future, so it creates a promise for it.